# How can we salvage the question "Are names of international figures still translated routinely in Mexican universities?"?

Tags: discusión, preguntas-cerradas, pregunta-específica

I would like to reopen [Are names of international figures still translated routinely in Mexican universities?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26101/9385), which is specifically focused on famous people whose names come up in Mexican institutions of higher education, names such as Adam Smith and Karl Marx.  Would it help to remove the second part ("What about other countries?")?

Any other ideas for how to rescue the question?

Comment: I think that the question was closed because it was perceived as a duplicate. I don't think that removing the second part would help making these questions significantly different. Reading the comments I see that DGaleano makes a good point, and the first part of the question seems a little bit off topic (the focus is "higher education" or "Mexican culture"). So, I guess that the question would be if the first part of the question is on-topic or not.

Comment: I think that I voted off-topic but the system only reports the majority view for all of us. If you delete the second part of the question I think it becomes more off-topic, if you delete the first it becomes more of a duplicate,