# Y tú ¿por qué no participas en Meta?

Tags: discusión, meta, usuarios, participación

En estos últimos tres o cuatro meses, quitando a los dos moderadores, **se pueden contar con los dedos de una mano los usuarios que han preguntado / respondido / comentado algo, *lo que sea*, en hilos de Meta** relacionados con Spanish.SE<sup>1</sup> — y sobran dedos:

aparente001, mdewey, y yo.

Y no será por falta de hilos en los que aportar algo:

<sub>- [Retrospectiva de 2018 en Spanish.se // Spanish.se 2018 Retrospective](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3015), por parte de nuestros moderadores.

- [2018: a year in moderation](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3017), por parte de un Community Manager de SO ([Shog9 ♦](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/users/83/shog9)).

- [Motivos de que se cerrase cierta pregunta y propuestas sobre cómo mejorarla.](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3018/how-can-we-salvage-the-question-are-names-of-international-figures-still-transl)

- [Would our site like to contribute an opinion to a Meta.SE question about difficulties sites like ours have trying to graduate from Beta?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3024)

- [¿Qué implicaciones tiene graduarse?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3029)

- [How do you decide whether to vote to close an iffy question?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034)

- [Shall we start making our own collection of false cognates, and if so, where?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3037)

- [Tag Housekeeping Requests](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2962)

- [How can we encourage participants to assist with the "review" queue?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3032)

- [¿Sobre qué elementos de revisión debemos evitar los mods ejercer el "binding vote"?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3044)</sub>

**¿Será que ningún otro usuario mínimamente veterano ha entrado al sitio durante este tiempo?**

[Al contrario](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=quarter): decenas de usuarios con reputación superior a 1000 puntos han participado de una manera u otra en el sitio principal durante este tiempo; y algunos de ellos, con relativa frecuencia.

Bajo mi punto de vista, lo normal en un stack sano, con una comunidad sana y donde se supone no hay problemas de ningún tipo, es que muchos de los usuarios activos de mayor reputación *quieran* participar en Meta.
Sin embargo, por algún motivo, parece que en Spanish.SE no es así.

A ver... Yo comprendo que algún que otro usuario veterano y activo no quiera participar en Meta, porque no le va, porque su uso del stack es diferente, porque no tiene tiempo... Un usuario. O dos. O diez.
Pero es que de lo que estamos hablando es que **más del 90% de los usuarios activos de Spanish.SE rechaza participar en Meta**.

No lo voy a negar: **esto me desconcierta, y mucho**. No paro de darle vueltas a la cabeza sobre los posibles motivos de que esto suceda, y me encantaría que esos usuarios me explicasen, nos explicasen, sus motivos para no participar. Y por eso voy a dar nombres:

`Rodrigo`, `Mike`, `rsanchez`, `VeAqui`, `leonbloy`, `Walter Mitty`, `Gorpik`, `prm296`, `dockeryZ`, `Fran`, `jrdioko`, `guifa`, `ukemi`, `pablodf76`, `angus`, `FGSUZ`, `Charlie`, `RubioRic`, `user5389726598465`, `Diego Mijelshon`, `Paco`, `DGaleano`, `Icarus`, `Gustavson`, `jlliagre`, `Flimzy♦`, `blonfu`, `AlexBcn`, `Lisa Beck`, `RubioRic`, `B. Clay Shannon`: ¿por qué no participáis en Meta?

¿Es por falta de tiempo?
¿Es porque no os interesa la moderación del sitio?
¿Es porque tenéis la sensación de que participar en Meta resulta estéril?
¿Es porque vosotros venís aquí a aprender, no a currar?
¿Es porque tenéis miedo de expresar una opinión contraria a la de algún usuario o moderador?
¿Es porque el estilo grisáceo de Meta os da grima comparado con el azulado del sitio principal?
¿Es porque os parece que los debates en Meta tienen demasiado "drama"?
¿Es porque alguien os cae mal?
¿Es porque consideráis que no tenéis suficiente conocimiento del sitio como para participar de manera útil?
¿Es porque tenéis la sensación de que el debate está monopolizado por solo unos pocos usuarios y no merece la pena participar?
¿Es porque os da vergüenza?

Son preguntas serias. **No acuso de nada ni echo en cara nada; solo intento comprender las razones de la bajísima participación en Meta, como única manera posible de poder proponer cambios** eficaces que la hagan más atractiva para nuestra comunidad.

Algunas de las razones que he planteado son, por así decirlo, "tema sensible". Motivos que, de ser ciertos, explicarían no solo que tal usuario no participe en Meta en general, sino que tampoco quiera responder públicamente a esta pregunta. Por tanto comento que, **si alguien no quiere expresar su opinión por aquí, puede mandarme un correo** a `walenzack@gmail.com`. Si soy yo el problema, se lo puede mandar entonces a fedorqui a la dirección de correo que él proporciona en [su perfil](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1674/fedorqui). (Nota: nada de lo que aquí he expuesto lo he hablado con él antes, pero entiendo que no tendrá pega en que un usuario le mande un correo para hablar de estas cosas.)

<sub><sup>1</sup> No cuento, por ejemplo, el hilo sobre Catalan.SE o el de los gorros de Winter Bash.</sub>

Comment: +1, porque la pregunta es interesante, pero no creo que sea bueno aludir a otros usuarios directamente por nombre. Creo que los mismos se pueden dar por aludidos sin necesidad de leer su _user ID_ en el post. Sé que no es tu intención crear una lista de "usuarios que no cumplen con alguna obligación" pero puede que otros no lo vean así. Nota: todavía estamos discutiendo [Moderators can now exclude questions from the HNQ list – when should we use this?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3047/5481) Quizá queramos comentar esto, antes de añadir el tag "featured" (que me parece bien)

Comment: Otros post aludidos [Catalan Language SE?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3023/5481) y el [¡Empieza el Winter Bash 2018! / Let the Winter Bash 2018 start!](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3012/5481). Tampoco es que la participación es estos sea muy distinta a los otros mencionados.

Comment: Discusión tangencial [movida al chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91038/discussion-on-question-by-walen-y-tu-por-que-no-participas-en-meta).

Answer (score 3):

Dejo aquí una respuesta-recopilatorio-resumen de las conclusiones que saco tras leer las respuestas ([la de Charlie](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3054), [la de aparente001](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3057), [la de Gorpik](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3059) y [la de blonfu](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3075)) y el chat ([comentarios de Rodrigo](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49626485#49626485)). Iré editando si llegan más respuestas de otros usuarios.

Factores que derivan en la no participación en Meta (más allá de la falta de tiempo):

- **Rechazo del rol "decisorio" que se suele asumir en Meta.**
  A algunos usuarios no les gusta participar de esa manera. Prefieren centrarse en el sitio principal.
- **Falta de interés en los temas tratados.**
  Algunos usuarios solo entran a Meta si ven algún tema que les interese.
- **Visibilidad ¿insuficiente?**
  A pesar de tirarse dos semanas enteras apareciendo en el panel *Featured* del sitio principal, algunos usuarios no vieron el post de Meta hasta que fue enlazado directamente dentro de otra pregunta "normal".
- **Algunos hilos requieren demasiado esfuerzo.**
  Preguntas y respuestas muy largas, con muchos enlaces y comentarios, echan para atrás a algunos usuarios.
- **Falta de eficacia.**
  Aunque no se haya calificado como un factor relevante, la sensación de que a veces los debates e iniciativas lanzados en Meta no sirven para mucho podría desanimar a algunos usuarios a participar en otros debates similares.
- **Hilos en inglés.**
  Los hilos y debates en inglés facilitan la participación de usuarios angloparlantes que están aprendiendo español, pero complican la de aquellos usuarios hispanohablantes que no dominan el inglés. Relevante en un sitio en el que es de esperar que la mayoría de usuarios con alta reputación hablen mejor español que inglés.

Si esos factores se pueden contrarrestar o no, y cómo, es algo que quedaría fuera del ámbito de la pregunta... pero algunas medidas, como la de [plantear los temas en forma de preguntas cortas y al grano](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A13628%20is%3Aquestion%20proposal), son obvias y de hecho ya las he aplicado antes con relativo éxito, tal como se puede ver en el enlace. Lo malo es que es difícil aplicar lo mismo a preguntas de tipo discusión.
En cualquier caso, por mi parte tomo nota y procuraré tener en cuenta estos puntos.

Comment: Sobre lo de visibilidad: ¿será porque visitan el sitio desde el teléfono móvil y, por tanto, el bloque de "featured" no les aparece?

Comment: @fedorqui yo casi siempre entro desde un pc y no "veo" ese bloque. No sé seguro si es por eso pero lo achaco a que está en una zona que históricamente se ha usado para bloques de publicidad y durante mucho tiempo antes de que existieran o yo descubriera los bloqueadores de anuncios mi cerebro dejó de ver esa zona de la pantalla.

Answer (score 2):

Huy, mi caso es muy sencillo: porque no me acuerdo de que existe. De verdad, solo recuerdo que existe Meta cuando hay algún asunto concreto que me interesa, lo que no es especialmente habitual. Hoy he venido aquí por la pregunta del *dejabugo* en el sitio principal.

Comment: @walen Más bien lo segundo. A lo mejor alguien menciona que algo se ha discutido en Meta, y entonces me acuerdo de que existe y entro aquí a verlo. También me ha ocurrido alguna vez lo primero que mencionas, es decir, se me ha ocurrido que tal vez se haya hablado de algún tema concreto aquí, pero es raro.

Answer (score 2):

Hablando solamente del caso mío,  la razón por la que no he participado en este Meta es que pienso que mi español no es tan fuerte como lo tenía pensado cuando ingresé al area.

En cuanto al estudio formal del idioma, solamente lo estudié en primaria.

En cuanto a preguntas sobra cómo se dice tal o cual cosa, mi español es una mezcla de regionalismos de Chile, Argentina, Colombia y Perú, y muchas veces no me acuerdo en cual país aprendí cual frase.  Y tengo también extranjerismos que vienen del hecho que mi lengua materna es el inglés.

Casi no empleo español en mi vida cotidiana,  actualmente.  Y la lengua es muy traidora.  Si no se usa se pierde.

A veces puedo aportar algo cuando una persona de habla inglesa pregunta algo que parece insensato al nativo español, pero que yo sí entiendo porque sé pensar en inglés.

Mi participación en el último año ha sido mayormente para satisfacer mi propia curiosidad.

Por otra parte, mi participación en todos los Metas ha decaído, porque muchas veces los Metas son dominados por lo que voy a llamar "inside baseball".  No sé cómo decir eso en español.

**Edit:**  And then there's Jeff Atwood's [infamous rant](https://blog.codinghorror.com/meta-is-murder/) about meta discussions.

Comment: Gracias por contarnos de tu experiencia, Walter.  Fíjate que si hay algo que te interesa, siempre puedes participar en inglés.  I do this quite a bit because English has been taking center stage in my life recently, and sometimes I feel unsure whether my ideas will come across completely clearly otherwise.  Maybe it's a cop out but people here have been quite tolerant. // The only way the insider feel can be remedied is if people speak up and ask, when something isn't clear -- so I hope you'll help out by asking or pointing ...

Comment: ... out when something isn't clear. (To be honest I feel completely lost in La Tertulia for that very reason; but the people who do participate there seem to find it quite rewarding so I haven't wanted to interrupt the flow there.)

Comment: Yes, people here have been quite tolerant.  When I first joined, I had thought I would have a lot of answers to provide.  Well, not so much.  I don't hesitate to ask when I want an answer.  But that isn't why I'm here, for the most part.

Comment: Tal vez me meta un poquito más en  Meta.

Answer (score 1):

Por alusiones.

> ¿Es por falta de tiempo?

Se podría decir. Prefiero invertir el tiempo en el sitio principal.

> ¿Es porque no os interesa la moderación del sitio?

Ciertamente. Personalmente en el sitio principal me encuentro bien y los temas de moderación no me interesan, salvo que sea algo que vaya a modificar sustancialmente la vida en dicho sitio principal. Según yo lo veo, hay gente más propensa a dejarse llevar por las decisiones de moderación que tomen los demás, y gente que prefiere estar en primera línea cuando se toman esas decisiones (sin que ello menoscabe su actividad en el sitio principal, por supuesto). Los primeros tenderán a quedarse en el sitio principal y a no asomarse mucho por Meta salvo cuando aparezcan cuestiones importantes. Los segundos sí visitarán Meta más a menudo y la usarán como corresponde. Personalmente me considero de los primeros.

> ¿Es porque tenéis la sensación de que participar en Meta resulta estéril?

No creo que sea estéril, para nada. Bueno, en algunos casos puede que sí, como en las preguntas sobre los repasos anuales del sitio, que cuando las veo siento un poco de *dejabugo* porque cada año me parecen igual, el sitio se mantiene en una pauta estable con leves altibajos. Muchas veces tratamos de hacer propuestas para mejorar el sitio pero nunca llegan a nada o el sitio simplemente acaba volviendo a su estacionario, como cuando hicimos el maratón de preguntas aquel.

> ¿Es porque vosotros venís aquí a aprender, no a currar?

No entiendo la pregunta. En el sitio principal se enseña y se aprende, con todo el curre que conlleva eso. No creo que Meta tenga que ver con las ganas de currar, porque muchas preguntas y respuestas tienen mucho trabajo detrás. Tiene más que ver con las ganas de tomar decisiones (ver respuesta a la pregunta de si no me interesa la moderación).

> ¿Es porque tenéis miedo de expresar una opinión contraria a la de algún usuario o moderador?

Tras varios años aquí ya he perdido el miedo a expresar ideas que puedan ser votadas negativamente. Quien tiene boca se equivoca, y no pasa nada, se acepta, se aprende y a seguir.

> ¿Es porque el estilo grisáceo de Meta os da grima comparado con el azulado del sitio principal?

No. :-D

> ¿Es porque os parece que los debates en Meta tienen demasiado "drama"?

No estoy seguro de si el "drama" o el hecho de que aquí las respuestas y comentarios tengan más intensidad me echa para atrás. Puede ser. Sí que ha habido debates intensos y estériles por aquí, ahora que lo pienso. Pero no creo que sea importante para responder a la cuestión principal.

> ¿Es porque alguien os cae mal?

En absoluto. Si alguien me cae mal simplemente lo ignoro.

> ¿Es porque consideráis que no tenéis suficiente conocimiento del sitio como para participar de manera útil?

No en mi caso. Ya no. Aunque cosas por aprender sobre cómo funciona todo esto me quedan, eso seguro.

> ¿Es porque tenéis la sensación de que el debate está monopolizado por solo unos pocos usuarios y no merece la pena participar?

No en mi caso, no sé si alguien más tendrá esa sensación, pero aquí solemos escuchar a todo el mundo que quiera decir algo, o eso quiero pensar.

> ¿Es porque os da vergüenza?

Puede que en algún momento me diera, pero ya no.

Lo gracioso es que respondiendo a esta pregunta ya estoy participando en Meta... La verdad es que cuando hay debates interesantes aquí sí que intento participar, aunque sea con algún comentario o simplemente votando. Pero preguntas la verdad es que hace tiempo que no hago.

Comment: @walen tienes toda la razón, me expresé muy mal ahí y siento que te doliera. Debí decir que hay gente más propensa que otros a simplemente dejarse llevar por las decisiones de los demás, y otros que prefieren estar en primera línea de las decisiones, sin que ello suponga un perjuicio (por supuesto) para su actividad en el sitio principal. Si te parece actualizo la respuesta para reflejar eso.

Answer (score 1):

A veces no participo porque no se me ocurre una pregunta, o porque no tengo nada nuevo que aportar en alguna pregunta planteada.

A veces es porque la pregunta es tan amplia que me da flojera leer las cantidades de texto o abrir gran número de tabs.

Pero la razón principal por no participar, cuando no participo, es porque temo perder mi enfoque en algún proyecto importante que me he planteado, ajeno a StackExchange.

Comment: @walen - Ha habido varios periodos de ausencia total.  Pero lo bueno de esto es que a veces cuando regreso encuentro una sorpresa grata, por ejemplo ahora encontré nuestro nuevo símbolo, la ñ.  ¡Cómo me gustaría verlo en las páginas también!

Answer (score 1):

Voy a participar en meta para explicar porque no participo en meta XD.

Por una parte me pasa como a @Gorpik que muchas veces olvido que existe, hasta que aparece en el feed del chat algún post o se comenta alguna cosa sobre meta.

También ocurre que una cantidad considerable de las publicaciones están en inglés y aunque me apaño (más o menos) para leerlo y quizá para escribir algo ayudandome de diccionarios y traductores me cuesta mucho seguir y participar en discusiones complejas.

Sí suelo leer las publicaciones cuando alguien lo comenta o me acuerdo de entrar y las voto cuando me parece que debo votar, es una forma de participar más pasiva pero válida también.

En cualquier caso meta es importante, ayuda a definir la dirección que toma el sitio, sirve para resolver conflictos, para aportar información y otras cosas pero el verdadero sitio es el principal y ahí es donde importa más la participación (la verdad que ahí tampoco estoy participando mucho últimamente pero ese es otro tema).