# An idea to increase Meta participation

Tags: discusión, meta, elementos-destacados, participación

Here's an idea for how to increase Meta participation: put links to our site Meta questions in the right-hand sidebar on our main site.  Yes, this happens occasionally, with a biggie.  But I'd like to see two or three mediummies put there too.  Because *out of sight, out of mind*.

Comment: Why? To what extend is increasing Meta participation necessary? Also, what you say is what [meta-tag:featured] does, as well as what is described in [What criteria are used to select the links that appear in the community bulletin sidebar block?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/209901)

Comment: Coincido con Fedorqui, lo que describes es el tag Featured y no podemos marcar todo como featured solo para darle visibilidad. Incluso así, es posible que no sirva para nada, porque hemos aprendido de esfuerzos similares anteriores que si la gente no participa en Meta es porque no quiere o ni sea acuerda de que existe (todo va lo suficientemente bien). El ejemplo más reciente que me viene a la cabeza es [Y tú ¿por qué no participas en Meta?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3049/5481) en la que creo que incluso se hizo un ping directo a muchos usuarios desde la propia pregunta y/o chat

Comment: Destaco de [la respuesta recopilación](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3064/5481) con "las conclusiones que saco tras leer las respuestas y el chat" del OP en la pregunta que he citado anteriormente (que creo que era el usuario anteriormente conocido como Walen): **Visibilidad ¿insuficiente?: A pesar de tirarse dos semanas enteras apareciendo en el panel Featured del sitio principal, algunos usuarios no vieron el post de Meta hasta que fue enlazado directamente dentro de otra pregunta "normal"**. Añadir la "visibilidad extra" no garantiza ni visitas ni participación (ni atención).

Comment: @Diego - No propongo esto como garantía, sino como un grano de arena.

Comment: @fedorqui - I recall reading something on Meta about how to help a beta site graduate, and it included a vibrant Meta.  Even though we left beta status in a strange way, kind of like when a PhD advisor sets an arbitrary defense date, after a certain number of years, I think all the reasoning in that context still applies.

Comment: Mi experiencia en Italian.SE (no tiene por qué ser igual aquí) es que esto sí que hace aumentar un poco la participación en Meta, pero tampoco demasiado. (No marcamos todas las preguntas como "featured", pero últimamente casi todas, porque son muy pocas).

Comment: @Charo  gracias.  Me gusta esto.  Cross-pollination!

Comment: @Charo, creo que eso es lo mismo que sucede en Spanish.se también. Ahora mismo solo hay un moderador activo (que son los únicos que pueden añadir este tag a una pregunta), así que el tag "featured" se añade bajo su discreción o tras sugerencia (hay que contactar al mod, pedírselo, etc.). Como se indica en el enlace de mi comentario anterior, Meta en Spanish.se recibe poca participación, pero creo se suelen marcar ya como featured las preguntas de discusión/voto, sobre todo las que afectarían al funcionamiento de la comunidad. No todas por supuesto, pero definir el umbral es bastante subjetivo.

Comment: También puedo añadir, por alguna experiencia que he tenido en otro sitio SE, que poner la etiqueta "featured" a ciertas preguntas en Meta parece atraer a los usuarios con ideas más extremas, mientras que la mayoría de los que tienen ideas moderadas, por alguna razón, deciden no participar. En alguna ocasión he tenido la sensación que pasa algo parecido a las muestras de voluntarios en estadística, es decir, que los resultados de los votos en el sitio Meta son poco representativos de la población.

Comment: Bueno, @Diego, escribí una respuesta a esta pregunta hace meses, pero ahora empiezo a tener serias dudas sobre su validez. Quizás es simplemente que han pasado cosas que han tenido como consecuencia que la participación (quién y cómo) en el sitio donde soy moderadora ha cambiado mucho en estos últimos meses. Es la triste realidad.

Comment: Creo que mis comentarios en este post iban más encaminados a la propuesta en particular de Aparente001. En lo referente e a la baja participación, se podría reabrir la conversación una vez más. No se cómo ha cambiado el sitio en el que eres mod (Italian.se?). Si lo quieres contar, via chat o lo que sea yo estaré encantado de escucharte. Este yo lo percibo como un poco más muerto de lo normal. Entiendo que estos meses de pandemia también han afectado un poco a los miembros regulares que eran el sostén del sitio y ahora lo mismo le pueden dedicar un poco menos de tiempo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En mi humilde opinión como novata en esta comunidad, estoy de acuerdo con lo expresado en los comentarios: no tiene sentido marcar todas las preguntas en Meta como "featured". Pero quizás sí que se podrían marcar algunas más de esta manera.

Según mi experiencia (lo admito: en otra comunidad y puede que el comportamiento de esta sea completamente diferente), es cierto que el panel "featured" del sitio principal pasa inadvertido a bastantes usuarios, pero hay otros (de acuerdo, no son muchos) que lo miran con regularidad y acceden para participar en Meta basándose sobretodo en lo que está enlazado allí. Por eso pienso que es bueno que se marquen como "featured" más preguntas en las que se pide votar entre diferentes opciones o se pide la opinión a la comunidad sobre temas que afectan a la organización del sitio principal, aunque, como ha dicho @aparente001, esto contribuya sólo como un granito de arena.